# How to make a message pop up(hover) when the player hits a time instant?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, html5-video, soundcloud

I want to do the same for a video player, I suspect it is no different because we are talking about the time instants irrespective of the player.
Like in [this link](http://p1.soundcloud.com/player.swf?amp=&amp=&amp=&amp=&amp=&amp=&amp=&auto_play=false&buying=false&color=626262&referer=&show_artwork=false&show_comments=true&show_playcount=false&theme_color=333333&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Fplaylists%2F1020073). 
So, what kind of coding goes into this?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of player would you be using? You see, in the example you posted a link to, you can rewind the player, and the timeline will reset to the current playback time, and so will the messages (comments) popping up. If your player does not support rewinding (time-jump). You could set the timeout when the user clicks play, and then show the popups respectively.

If however your player supports the feature of moving the playhead, first we (at least I do) need to know what kind of player you'd be using. If it is a Audio API based player, I can help you.

Hope this clarifies things for you.

Comment: Yes, I would be using an audio player.